# Getting "element timed out after 60 seconds" exception in MBUnit framework

Tags: timeout, mbunit

I am using `selenium(C#)` **MBUnit** framework.

I have put `Thread.Sleep(60000)` statement in my test.

While executing above statement using Gallio Icarus, I am getting below exception.

```
element timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
```

What is the default timeout between two selenium commands in **MBUnit**?

Answer (score 0):

There are three different settings for timeouts I know of... ImplicitWait, PageLoadTimeout, and ScriptTimeout.

- ImplicitWait tells the browser how long to look for an element before quitting.
- ScriptTimeout is how long a script should run before quitting.
- PageLoadTimeout, is well, how long we should let a page load before timing out.

My guess is that the ScriptTimeout is getting exceeded. Try running the following code before your sleep statement.

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts.SetScriptTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 70, 0)) ; 
Driver.Manage().Timeouts.SetPageLoadTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 70, 0)) ;
```

If you have any background request going that might make Selenium think there is an ongoing operation (AJAX?) try setting the ImplicitWait higher also.